# Compare two arrays of unknown type

Tags: java, arrays, junit, compare

When writing some generic test logic, I often use reflection. In the given situation I loop over all fields of a class and compare the values of the fields. These fields can be of array types so I have to distinguish this:

```
Field[] fields = beanBeforeStore.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
or (Field field : fields) {
    ...
    if (field.getType().isArray()) {
       // How to best compare?
    }
    ...
}
```

This is all part of a `JUnit` test which provides `assertArrayEquals` which is overloaded for primitive type arrays and object arrays. So in order to compare I have to cast the values to an array type.
As I want to keep this part generic I have the problem that the array can be of a primitive type or of any object type. What is the best way to do it?

Some background information: This logic is part of the testing of saved objects. As the object is not persisted as a whole, but only the data (no need to serialize services that in turn may reference other objects). The tests for each field need to be specific. Some fields need to be the same and other fields need to be identical (through equals). While some of the objects implement the equals method, not all fields that need to be checked are part of the equals logic.

Comment: This seems pretty bloated for a test. Can you give a more concrete example?  I smell an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(array1, array2);
```

Comment: array1 and array2 have to be of type `Object[]`. How do I get there from a field that can be of type Object[] (or a subtype of object) or of type int[]. In the case of an int array you get a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not avoid reflection where reasonable. Otherwise, from the sound of it, `Objects.equals` would appear to fit.